# Get Sub-domain with PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, subdomain, server-name

How to get sub domain from URL. let say `subdomain.example.com`, then i want only `subdomain`

Example :

```
https://subdomain.example.com
https://anything.example.com/pathurl
```

Output :

```
Subdomain
anything
```

Trying code from stackoverflow with some modification but did not work :(

```
$subdomain = substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],0,4) === '/^([^.]+)/' ? substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],0) : $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
echo $subdomain;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, to break down your attempt:

- `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` gives you the full server name, e.g. "subdomain.example.com"
- `substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],0,4)` gives you the first four characters of that string; it's likely the example you copied from was looking for "www.", which is four characters long, but "subd" isn't going to tell you much
- `===` just compares that two things are identical; since you've just asked for four characters, it's never going to match a string of any other length
- `'/^([^.]+)/'` looks like a [Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions) (aka "regex") - a pattern to match strings; to use that in PHP, you need [the PCRE family of functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php), such as `preg_match` and `preg_replace`

Next, the tip I always give: break the problem down. Forget for a moment that you know what a sub-domain is, and notice that you have a string, and want all the text up to the first dot.

One way to get that is therefore to split the string on *every* dot, and take the first part. For that, you would use the excitingly named [explode](https://www.php.net/explode):

```
$subdomain = explode('.', $fulldomain, 1)[0];
```

Another way would be using the regex pattern you found, which reads "starting at the beginning, match anything but a dot, at least once, and capture that part". You can actually skip one pair of brackets, because they're grouping the whole pattern, so just `'/^[^.]+/'` is enough. To do that, you'd use [preg_match](https://www.php.net/preg_match), but note that it doesn't *return* the matched parts, it puts them in an extra array you pass to it:

```
$matches = null; // will be populated by preg_match
preg_match('/^[^.]+/', $fulldomain, $matches);
$subdomain = $matches[0];
```

**Note:** The above will return "stackoverflow" for an input of "stackoverflow.com". That is unavoidable with simple string matching, because there is no standard number of segments that mark a "public domain" - e.g. "bbc.co.uk" is registered at the same level as "bbc.com", but you can't tell that by looking at them. Unless you know in advance what your possible endings will be, you need something that checks the [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/), such as [the php-domain-parser library](https://github.com/jeremykendall/php-domain-parser).

Comment: the problem of this is if there's no subdomain it will return the host

Comment: @Jerson Unless you integrate the [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/), that is inevitable: there is no universal distinction between "domain" and "sub-domain". I'll edit in a warning to that effect.

Answer (score 2):

You could use regex.

```
preg_match('/^[^.]*\.(?=\w+\.\w+$)/',$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],$matches);

$subdomain = isset($matches[0]) ? trim($matches[0],'.') : '';

echo $subdomain;
```

here is the [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/dOdAH)

Comment: This returns empty for anything with more than three segments in the domain, e.g. "softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com" or "www.bbc.co.uk"; my answer would return "softwareengineering" and "www" for those; a library using the Public Suffix List would be able to give you "softwareengineering.meta" and "www".

Comment: [Demo1](https://3v4l.org/PiLPu) and [Demo2](https://3v4l.org/CbE1l) This just does not work

Comment: @RiggsFolly in demo1 op use SERVER NAME so it will not return the scheme, in demo 2 it will empty because there subdomain in the url, but threew segments will not work in this

Comment: there's no subdomain, typo error my bad

Answer (score 2):

Using a mixture of `parse_url()` and `strtok()` like this

```
$url = 'https://anything.example.com/pathurl';

$bits = parse_url($url);
$sub = strtok($bits['host'], '.');
echo $sub;
```

RESULTS

```
anything
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ClIW0)

Comment: I tried `$url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$bits = parse_url($url);
$sub = strtok($bits['host'], '.');
echo $sub;` but no result

Comment: Well that depends on whats in `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` can you echo that and show me

Comment: `echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];` result is `www.example.com`

Comment: Well that shoudl show `example`

Comment: But in above `www.example.com` it should show `www` right? because `www` is a sub-domain.

Comment: Check here : https://3v4l.org/R08Sg it giving error and for me also it showing a black page.

Comment: See demo. Not sure what you are doing.

Comment: PS You cannot access `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];` in that tool

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @IMSoP , @RiggsFolly and @Jerson. All of your code work amazing :)

For my own future reference :

```
$fulldomain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$matches = null; 
preg_match('/^[^.]+/', $fulldomain, $matches);
$subdomain = $matches[0];

echo $subdomain;
```